# How to access the facebook smart list?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanted my application to post a status on users wall which should be seen only by the persons in that locale? How is it possible to restrict it in facebook apis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for a Post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) has a detailed list of all fields, one of them is the *"privacy"* which controls who will see the post, it says:

> object containing the value field and optional friends, networks,
>   allow, deny and description fields. .... The description field may
>   contain a comma-separated lists of valid country, city and language if
>   a Page's post targeting by location/language is specified.

I recommend that you go and check it out since it has much more text written on this field.